# Task.Factory and factory pattern

Tags: design-patterns, task, task-parallel-library, factory

Factory Method pattern is mostly used/recommended to be used while creating an object belonging to a sub-class (there should be multiple sub-classes too). One such definition from [dofactory](https://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern):

> Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses.

Given this definition, is it apt for `Task.Factory` to be an example of Factory Method pattern, as there are no sub-classes for `Task` class' parents?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this question from Head First Design Patterns and I am pasting as it is from the book.  So the credits go to the authors..

> The Factory Method Pattern is useful if you’ve only got one concrete creator because you are decoupling the implementation of the product [Task] from its use. If you add additional products or change a product’s implementation, it will not affect your Creator (because the Creator is not tightly coupled to any ConcreteProduct).

Creator being the `Task.Factory` in this case.